# how do I show a detail content in Google Drive APIs?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I use Google Drive APIs.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files

When clicking on a link, we use webViewLink to show the page of view.

But I want to show detail contents...

Please refer to the attached image.

I want to show the part of the red frame.

【[google drive img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Td1Sf.png)】

How to show a detail content in Google Drive APIs?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the details of the file you can use the **[`Files: get`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get)** method:

> Gets a file's metadata by ID.

Here is a sample code for javascript:

```
/**
   * Print files.
   */
  function listFiles() {
    gapi.client.drive.files.list({
      'pageSize': 10,
      'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
    }).then(function(response) {
      appendPre('Files:');
      var files = response.result.files;
      if (files && files.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          var file = files[i];
          appendPre(file.name + ' (' + file.id + ')');
        }
      } else {
        appendPre('No files found.');
      }
    });
  }
```

Do note that in v3, full resources are no longer returned by default. Use the fields query parameter to request specific fields to be returned. If left unspecified only a subset of commonly used fields are returned.

Hope this helps.